# typescript calling connected child ref instance method

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

to be simple, I have a child component connected by redux

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    foo () {}
}

export default connect()(Child);
```

and a parent contains it

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    childRef: React.RefObject<Child> = React.createRef()

    bar () {
        if (this.childRef.current) {
            /*
             * here typescript complains that 
             * Property 'foo' does not exist on
             * type 'ConnectedComponentClass<typeof Child...'
             */
            this.childRef.current.foo();
        }
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <Child ref={this.childRef} />
        );
    }
}
```

I've tried to set the generic type

```
<React.ComponentType<Child>>
```

explicitly when exporting child component, but still not working.

Comment: Did anybody else find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and couldn't find a legitimate solution. I did, however, manage to hack it by redeclaring the child component with type 'any', like so:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    childRef: React.RefObject<Child> = React.createRef()

    bar () {
        if (this.childRef.current) {
            const childRef: any = this.childRef.current;
            childRef.foo();
        }
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <Child ref={this.childRef} />
        );
    }
}
```

If you ever managed to come up with a better solution i'd like to hear it.